# UberSuggest SEO tool says “low word count” for AJAX powered site with lots of words

Tags: seo, ajax, single-page-application, word-count

We have a website - https://huspi.com - and I connected it to the UberSuggest SEO tool. Our website uses Express JS as well as a few other JS libraries and is technically a single-page application, despite having many pages.

For some reason, it keeps showing the error of "Low words count" - even on blog article pages, which have over 2,500 words...

Did anyone have a case like this and how to fix it? I have no idea how to describe the task for our developers to fix this issue.